# Interface variable declaration: synthesizing and unknown selector

Tags: objective-c

I'm having a confusing problem. I'm only ankle deep in Objective-C so I'll try my best to explain. I have a class, which is a controller that simply declares an NSTextField which is in a nib file.

Here's its declaration in the interface file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
```

and in the implementation:

```
@synthesize textField;
```

Simple right? But if I call `[textField stringValue]` on it later on by means of clicking on a submit button then it fails with an unknown selector message (typical if it thinks it can't call that message on that object type). This looked like this:

```
-(IBAction)send:(id)sender {
    NSString* txt = [textField stringValue];
    [server send:txt];
}
```

To fix this, I did the following:

```
@interface MyController : NSObject {
    NSTextField *textField;
}
```

I've not seen any tutorial/example showing this. They do it without declaring the NSTextField in this section of the interface.

My question is, why in my case do I have to declare it in the interface for it to work?

Comment: I assumed you have linked the IBAction up in interface builder?

Comment: @geminiCoder that has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Also, @OP: please post the exact error message you're getting.

Comment: I know, you should be using `[textField.text stringValue]` the textField itself doesn't respond to stringValue

Comment: Bah, ops close. I just removed the interface declaration and it works now. Very confused. This question no longer applies.